# Sending a .zip file from MacBook Pro desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, zip

I made my Xcode project into a .zip file. Can I send it via email as an attachment? Would it work that the person I send the project to, can unzip my file and see my entire Xcode project?

Comment: This borders on too broad. What happens when you try emailing yourself the project? How can we know what size you made your project? How can we guess if your project is self contained or not? This also borders on basic customer support. Try to do some research and show that research in your question to explain how it didn't help you solve this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That will work.

If it's too big to email, use a cloud service (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.) and email them the link.

Even if it's not too big for an attachment, you might consider sending them a link so they can download at their convenience, rather than having you 'push' the file into their inbox.